# Running the Rails Application with rails version 2.3.2 on Rails 5 configured environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have install rails 5 and create the application successfully. But I have an application which is created on rails 2.3.2, Do I able to test the application on my machine, which have rails 5

I have try to create an application (`rails _2.3.2_ new my_app`) using rails 2.3.2 version for this I got the following error. That is railties not found. How do I fix this

```
/home/techorin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb :319:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (= 2.3.2) - did find: [railties-5.0.0.1,railties-4.2.6,railties-4.2.1,railties-4.1.2] (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/home/techorin/.gem/ruby/2.3.0:/home/techorin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0', execute `gem env` for more information
from /home/techorin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:328:in `to_spec'
from /home/techorin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `gem'
from /home/techorin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What's your output when you run the command `gem list | grep railties`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 2.3 is pre the use of bundler in rails. You can try installing the rails 2.3 via `gem install rails -v 2.3.2` and rely on the gem handling of rails.

As you are using rbenv, you could also consider using a gemset.  I use rvm where this is built in, but it appears that https://github.com/jf/rbenv-gemset will give you this sort of functionality on rbenv.   This will allow you to create a sandboxed version (maybe with a different version of ruby as well) to continue to run your rails 2.3 app.

But getting it run inside 5.x, you would need to upgrade your application to the new framework (lots of rails upgrades) as there have been a lot of changes.